# Electra sequence classification with pytorch lightning issues with 'pooler_output'

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I'm working on a sentence classification task with multiple binary labels attached to each sentence. I'm using Electra and pytorch lightning to do the job, but I've run into a problem. When I'm running the `trainer.fit(model, data)` I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pooler_output'`

The error is referring to line 13 in the section where I'm defining `pl.LightningModule`:

```
class CrowdCodedTagger(pl.LightningModule):

  def __init__(self, n_classes: int, n_training_steps=None, n_warmup_steps=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.electra = ElectraModel.from_pretrained(ELECTRA_MODEL_NAME, return_dict=False) #changed ElectraModel to ElectraForSequenceClassification
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.electra.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
    self.n_training_steps = n_training_steps
    self.n_warmup_steps = n_warmup_steps
    self.criterion = nn.BCELoss()

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
    output = self.electra(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    output = self.classifier(output.pooler_output) # <---- this is the line the error is referring to.
    output = torch.sigmoid(output)
    loss = 0
    if labels is not None:
        loss = self.criterion(output, labels)
    return loss, output

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("train_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return {"loss": loss, "predictions": outputs, "labels": labels}

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("val_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
    attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"]
    labels = batch["labels"]
    loss, outputs = self(input_ids, attention_mask, labels)
    self.log("test_loss", loss, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
    return loss

  def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    
    labels = []
    predictions = []
    for output in outputs:
      for out_labels in output["labels"].detach().cpu():
        labels.append(out_labels)
      for out_predictions in output["predictions"].detach().cpu():
        predictions.append(out_predictions)

    labels = torch.stack(labels).int()
    predictions = torch.stack(predictions)

    for i, name in enumerate(LABEL_COLUMNS):
      class_roc_auc = auroc(predictions[:, i], labels[:, i])
      self.logger.experiment.add_scalar(f"{name}_roc_auc/Train", class_roc_auc, self.current_epoch)

  def configure_optimizers(self):

    optimizer = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=2e-5)

    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
      optimizer,
      num_warmup_steps=self.n_warmup_steps,
      num_training_steps=self.n_training_steps
    )

    return dict(
      optimizer=optimizer,
      lr_scheduler=dict(
        scheduler=scheduler,
        interval='step'
      )
    )
```

Can anyone point me in a direction to fix the error?

EXAMPLE OF DATA STRUCTURE (in CSV):

```
sentence                      label_1          label_2          label_3
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet    1                0                1
consectetur adipiscing elit   0                0                0
sed do eiusmod tempor         0                1                1
incididunt ut labore et       1                0                0
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet    1                0                1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ELECTRA](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/electra#transformers.ElectraModel) has no [pooler layer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/31ec2cb2badfbdd4c1ac9c6c9b8a74e974984206/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L627) like [BERT](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel) (compare the return section for further information).

In case you only want to use the [CLS] token for your sequence classification, you can simply take the first element of the last_hidden_state (initialize electra without `return_dict=False`):

```py
output = self.classifier(output.last_hidden_state[:, 0])
```